# There isn't antlib.xml in my ant-contrib-0.3

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I am trying to use task `for`. I tried with this task definition:

```
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${infrastructure-base-dir}/apache-ant-1.9.6/lib/ant-contrib-0.3.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
```

But didn't work. This message appear:

> Problem: failed to create task or type for

So I decider to unzip `ant-contrib-0.3.jar` to see what's inside. And there wasn't `antlib.xml` in this path: `net/sf/antcontrib/`. So what would you advise me in order to make **task FOR** to work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. In your build.xml

   `<taskdef name="for-contrib" classname="net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask" classpath="${basedir}/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />`
2. Place jar file file in correct location, i.e. in lib folder at same level as build.xml.
3. Use the for as needed, i.e

   `<for-contrib list="a,b,c,d,e" param="letter">
     <sequential>
       <echo>Letter @{letter}</echo>
     </sequential>
   </for>`

[For task documentation](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html)

Comment: I solved the problem downloading another library `antcontrib.jar.zip`. It is much more complete than `ant-contrib-0.3`.

Answer (score 0):

The following build file will install Ant contrib automatically

```
<project name="ant-contrib-tasks" default="build">

    <available classname="net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask" property="contrib.installed"/>

    <target name="install-contrib" unless="contrib.installed">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ant-contrib.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=ant-contrib/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
        <fail message="Ant Contrib installed - Run Ant again"/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="install-contrib">
      <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>

        <for param="file">
            <fileset dir="." includes="*.txt"/>
            <sequential>
                <echo message="Found file @{file}"/>
            </sequential>
        </for>
    </target>

</project>
```