# failed to create task or type com.***.***.<ClassName>

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a build file in a eclipse project. The build file tries to invoke a java class located in another project of the same eclipse workspace.

Below is the simple source of the calling ant file.

```
<target name="blah">
         <antcall target="invokeJavaClass"/>
</target>
<target name="invokeJavaClass">
        <com.abc.def.SampleClassName>
               <parameter name="param1" value="value1" />
               <parameter name="param1" value="value1" />
        </com.abc.def.SampleClassName>
</target>
```

The build fails with
 "failed to create task or type com.abc.def.SampleClassName"
  Cause: The name is undefined.
  Action: Check the spelling.
  Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
  Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

I have included the `ant-contrib-1.0b3` in the `classpath` and included the taskdef for `net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml`

I have spent 3 days trying to figure this out and still haven't progressed from ground zero. 
Could someone please give some pointers ?

Comment: Have you included that _other_ project on the classpath as well? On the Java Build Path?

Comment: Yes, I have included and referenced the class path in this project.

Answer (score 0):

The following error message is issued by ANT when it encounters an XML tag that it does not understand

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

  <target name="build">
    <i.am.an.invalid.task>
    </i.am.an.invalid.task>
  </target>

</project>
```

For example

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/mark/tmp/build.xml:4: Problem: failed to create task or type i.am.an.invalid.task
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

To extend ANT with custom tasks you must either explicitl declare it with a [task definition](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/taskdef.html) or else create an [ANT lib](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html).

Since you mentioned ant-contrib, could the following question be your issue?

- [There isn't antlib.xml in my ant-contrib-0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351322/there-isnt-antlib-xml-in-my-ant-contrib-0-3/34361910#34361910)