# Ant lib cannot be found in Cygwin

Tags: ant, cygwin, ant-contrib

I added ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar into ANT lib folder. But when I executed ANT performance monitor task in **Cygwin**, it still reported CLASS NOT FOUND.

However, if I do same job in Windows command-line, the building is working fine.

Is there anyone knows what is going on?

BTW, I confirmed that WIN-CMD and Cygwin are using same ANT.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

- [There isn't antlib.xml in my ant-contrib-0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351322/there-isnt-antlib-xml-in-my-ant-contrib-0-3/34361910#34361910)

Create a target that automatically installs ant-contrib if it's missing.