# Trying to make this target conditional

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<target name="example">
   <if>
      <equals arg1="${var}" arg2="true" />
      <then>
         <exec executable="/bin/bash">
            <arg value="script.sh" />
         </exec>
      </then>
   </if>
</target>
```

And when I execute the target with ant example I get this error:

```
Problem: failed to create task or type if
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

I really need help in here. I would really appreciate it

Comment: The following answer demonstrates how to install the missing 3rd party dependency: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351322/there-isnt-antlib-xml-in-my-ant-contrib-0-3/34361910#34361910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because, `if` is custom task from `ant-contrib` library.

Make sure, *ant-contrib* library in your class path. Binaries can be downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/1.0b3/).  Extract the ant-contrib jar file to a location. And specify the same in below *taskdef*.

Then add the *taskdef* at the beginning of the *build.xml*. Refer [documentation](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) for more details.

For eg:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="/absolute/path/to/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```